# NullPointerException in onCreate of Activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, oncreate

I have a splash page that opens up when my app is open, and then it is replaced by a `LoginActivity` that gives the option to the user of logging into Twitter with the app.  This is the onCreate method of `LoginActivity`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    Log.i("here", "login has started");
    Button loginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitterLoginButton);
    Button noLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noLoginButton);
    loginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        /**
         * Login via Twitter
         */
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    noLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        /**
         * Proceed to use app without login
         */
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}
```

When the app is started up, the splash displays fine, but the LoginActivity brings about a NullPointerException pointing specifically at the line 29, which is: `loginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

I cannot even begin to understand why this is happening.  Does anyone have any idea?  Logcat below:

```
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tforan.blobtag4/com.tforan.blobtag4.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1852)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1873)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4358)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at com.tforan.blobtag4.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:29)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
06-25 00:06:21.000: E/AndroidRuntime(4809):     ... 11 more
```

I should add that this was working fine as is until updating my ADT, Play services, etc.  Thank you for the help!

activity_login.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#D0E4F7"
tools:context=".LoginActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loginLogo"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/twitterLoginButton"
    style="@style/buttonText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/loginLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/signinwithtwitter"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/noLoginButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/twitterLoginButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:text="@string/declineLogin" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you think eclipse is a culprit after updating ADT then [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16603961/2345913)

Comment: Please, provide activity_login.xml

Comment: activity_login.xml added

Comment: use Activity context `Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class)`. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code may be help to you

Just change

```
 loginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

instead of

```
 loginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Use this solution

```
 Button loginTwitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.twitterLoginButton);
    Button noLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.noLoginButton);
    loginTwitter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        /**
         * Login via Twitter
         */
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    noLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        /**
         * Proceed to use app without login
         */
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Comment: this made the error go away.  thank you!  will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you have no control with the ID `R.id.twitterLoginButton`, so `findViewById` returns NULL.

If you see this control in your layout file, you should try and build again (Project menu, Clean build files).

Answer (score 0):

Check the manifest LoginActivity is in right path with package name or not..

if it is proper copy below files form any working project and replace in your project..

```
ant.properties
build.xml
proguard-project.txt
project.properties
.classpath
.project
```